# Creating different controller with same name but different route Prefix

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I want to create two api requests (in C#, WebAPI)

1) http://localhost:port/api/Title
2) http://localhost:port/api/Custom/Title

In both the above cases, Title is controller which I have to create. So for 1 api I created the following controller

```
[RoutePrefix("api")]
public class TitleController : ApiController
{
    [Route("Title")]
    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult Post(string programmeName, string titleType = "M", int estimatedDuration=0)
   {
   }
}
```

The above controller is in \Title\TitleController.cs

For 2 api I created below:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/Custom")]
public class TitleController : ApiController
{
    [Route("Title")]
    public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody] TitleModel titleModel)
    {
    }
}
```

The above controller is in \Custom\Title\TitleController.cs

And I have configured my WebApiConfig.cs to have both routes

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(name: "DefaultApi", routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}", defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(name: "CustomApi", routeTemplate: "api/Custom/{controller}/{id}", defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(config);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(config);
    }
}
```

When I make a call to api 2, I get the following error

```
{
   "Message": "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI  'http://localhost:872/api/Custom/Title'.",
   "MessageDetail": "No type was found that matches the controller named 'Custom'."
}
```

ANd sometimes I get an error saying more than one Title Controller exists and not allowed.

How do I resolve this issue, other than naming one of the controller differently

Comment: First you should name them differently. Secondly there is a missing "HttpPost" attribute on the api/Custom action. You are confusing convention-based and attribute routing

Comment: Are the two controllers in separate namespaces? If so then attribute routing should allow for that flexibility

Comment: Not possible as my understanding, try to name diffirently

Comment: @Nkosi: Agreed the HttpPost attribute was left by accident
and yes they are in two different namespaces.

Yea trying to name them differently is an option. But I was wondering if this is possible or not.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the convention routing you have

```
 config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(name: "DefaultApi", routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}", defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(name: "CustomApi", routeTemplate: "api/Custom/{controller}/{id}", defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });
```

and just use the attribute routing in your classes.

Comment: Yea done that, but I dont think the "CustomApi" config.route makes a difference